# lxml pretty_print python memory overload

Tags: python, parsing, lxml, pretty-print

I have a poorly formatted xml file with over 350 MB of data. Basically, all the data was consolidated into one line. I am trying to pretty_print this into a new file to make life easier, but am running into memory issues. Am I doing anything wrong here and is there a way around this? My computer has 4GB of RAM and is a Quad-Core i5-2410M (2.30Ghz)

```
import os
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse('filename',parser)
f = open('filename',"w")
f.write(etree.tostring(tree,pretty_print=True))
f.close()
```

Comment: If you only want to format the document, `xmlformat` is a great utility: http://www.kitebird.com/software/xmlformat/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try using the write method directly with the file handle rather than calling tostring. Change this line:

```
f.write(etree.tostring(tree,pretty_print=True))
```

to this:

```
tree.write(f, pretty_print=True)
```

This should hopefully reduce the memory usage by half.